# Android Studio: Bluetooth Low Energy BLE Advertisements

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

on line 370 i need a way to look for a string of 'f's' in the advertisement data from a TI CC2650. I found this template online but I'm looking for specific advertising data. Please let me know what string array I need to look at to find this.
[image: ScreenShot]

```
package net.jmodwyer.beacon.beaconPoC;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;

import net.jmodwyer.ibeacon.ibeaconPoC.R;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.utils.UrlBeaconUrlCompressor;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Adapted from original code written by D Young of Radius Networks.
 * @author dyoung, jodwyer
 *
 */
public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer,
                                                        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                                                        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Constant Declaration
    private static final String PREFERENCE_SCANINTERVAL = "scanInterval";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_POWER = "power";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_PROXIMITY = "proximity";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_RSSI = "rssi";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_MAJORMINOR = "majorMinor";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_UUID = "uuid";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_INDEX = "index";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_REALTIME = "realTimeLog";
    private static final String MODE_SCANNING = "Stop Scanning";
    private static final String MODE_STOPPED = "Start Scanning";
    protected static final String TAG = "ScanActivity";

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int
            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private FileHelper fileHelper; 
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private Region region;
    private int eventNum = 1;

    // This StringBuffer will hold the scan data for any given scan.  
    private StringBuffer logString;

    // Preferences - will actually have a boolean value when loaded.
    private Boolean index;
    private Boolean location;
    private Boolean uuid;
    private Boolean majorMinor;
    private Boolean rssi;
    private Boolean proximity;
    private Boolean power;
    private Boolean timestamp;
    private String scanInterval;
    // Added following a feature request from D.Schmid.
    private Boolean realTimeLog;

    // LocationClient for Google Play Location Services
    LocationClient locationClient;

    private ScrollView scroller;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        verifyBluetooth();
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        BeaconScannerApp app = (BeaconScannerApp)this.getApplication();
        beaconManager = app.getBeaconManager();
        //beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(10);
        region = app.getRegion();
        beaconManager.bind(this);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        fileHelper = app.getFileHelper();
        scroller = (ScrollView)ScanActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.scanScrollView);
        editText = (EditText)ScanActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.scanText);
        // Initialise scan button.
        getScanButton().setText(MODE_STOPPED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Uncommenting the following leak prevents a ServiceConnection leak when using the back
        // arrow in the Action Bar to come out of the file list screen. Unfortunately it also kills
        // background scanning, and as I have no workaround right now I'm settling for the lesser of
        // two evils.
        // beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    public String getCurrentLocation() {
        /** Default "error" value is set for location, will be overwritten with the correct lat and
         *  long values if we're ble to connect to location services and get a reading.
         */
        String location = "Unavailable";
        if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
            Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
            if (currentLocation != null) {
                location = Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude()) + "," +
                        Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude());
            }
        }
        return location;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {}

    /**
     * 
     * @param view
     */
    public void onScanButtonClicked(View view) {
        toggleScanState();
    }

    // Handle the user selecting "Settings" from the action bar.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Settings:
                // Show settings
                Intent api = new Intent(this, AppPreferenceActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(api, 0);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_listfiles:
                // Launch list files activity
                Intent fhi = new Intent(this, FileHandlerActivity.class);
                startActivity(fhi);
                return true;                                
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     }

    /**
     * Start and stop scanning, and toggle button label appropriately.
     */
    private void toggleScanState() {
        Button scanButton = getScanButton();
        String currentState = scanButton.getText().toString();
        if (currentState.equals(MODE_SCANNING)) {
            stopScanning(scanButton);
        } else {
            startScanning(scanButton);
        }
    }

    /**
     * start looking for beacons.
     */
    private void startScanning(Button scanButton) {

        // Set UI elements to the correct state.
        scanButton.setText(MODE_SCANNING);
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.scanText)).setText("");

        // Reset event counter
        eventNum = 1;
        // Get current values for logging preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);        
        HashMap <String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.putAll(sharedPrefs.getAll());

        index = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_INDEX);
        location = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_LOCATION);
        uuid = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_UUID);
        majorMinor = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_MAJORMINOR);
        rssi = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_RSSI); 
        proximity = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_PROXIMITY);
        power = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_POWER);
        timestamp = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_TIMESTAMP);
        scanInterval = (String)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_SCANINTERVAL);
        realTimeLog = (Boolean)prefs.get(PREFERENCE_REALTIME);

        // Get current background scan interval (if specified)
        if (prefs.get(PREFERENCE_SCANINTERVAL) != null) {
            beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Long.parseLong(scanInterval));
        }

        logToDisplay("Scanning...");

        // Initialise scan log
        logString = new StringBuffer();

        //Start scanning again.
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Iterator <Beacon> beaconIterator = beacons.iterator();
                    while (beaconIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Beacon beacon = beaconIterator.next();
                        // Debug - logging a beacon - checking background logging is working.
                        System.out.println("Logging another beacon.");
                        logBeaconData(beacon);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {   
            // TODO - OK, what now then?
        }   

    }

    /**
     * Stop looking for beacons.
     */
    private void stopScanning(Button scanButton) {
        try {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO - OK, what now then?
        }
        String scanData = logString.toString();
        if (scanData.length() > 0) {
            // Write file
            fileHelper.createFile(scanData);
            // Display file created message.
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "File saved to:" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scanButton.setText(MODE_STOPPED);
        } else {
            // We didn't get any data, so there's no point writing an empty file.
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "No data captured during scan, output file will not be created.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scanButton.setText(MODE_STOPPED);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return reference to the start/stop scanning button
     */
    private Button getScanButton() {
        return (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param beacon The detected beacon
     */
    private void logBeaconData(Beacon beacon) {

        StringBuilder scanString = new StringBuilder();

        if (index) {
            scanString.append(eventNum++);
        }

        if (beacon.getServiceUuid() == 0xfeaa) {

            if (beacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x00) {

                scanString.append(" Eddystone-UID -> ");
                scanString.append(" Namespace : ").append(beacon.getId1());
                scanString.append(" Identifier : ").append(beacon.getId2());

                logEddystoneTelemetry(scanString, beacon);

            } else if (beacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x10) {

                String url = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.uncompress(beacon.getId1().toByteArray());
                scanString.append(" Eddystone-URL -> " + url);

            } else if (beacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x20) {

                scanString.append(" Eddystone-TLM -> ");
                logEddystoneTelemetry(scanString, beacon);

            }

        } else {

            // Just an old fashioned iBeacon or AltBeacon...
            logGenericBeacon(scanString, beacon);

        }

        logToDisplay(scanString.toString());
        scanString.append("\n");

        // Code added following a feature request by D.Schmid - writes a single entry to a file
        // every time a beacon is detected, the file will only ever have one entry as it will be
        // recreated on each call to this method.
        // Get current background scan interval (if specified)
        if (realTimeLog) {
            // We're in realtime logging mode, create a new log file containing only this entry.
            fileHelper.createFile(scanString.toString(), "realtimelog.txt");
        }

        logString.append(scanString.toString());

    }

    /**
     * Logs iBeacon & AltBeacon data.
     */
    private void logGenericBeacon(StringBuilder scanString, Beacon beacon) {

        // Comment stuff out for whatever reason
        /*

        if (location) {
            scanString.append(" Location: ").append(getCurrentLocation()).append(" ");
        }
`
        */

        if (uuid) {
            scanString.append(" UUID: ").append(beacon.getId1());

            if (beacon.getId1().equals("ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff ")){
                scanString.append("WE DID IT!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }else{
                scanString.append("  WE DID NOT DO IT  =(  ");
            }

            /*

            if ((beacon.getId1()).equals ("f")){

                scanString.append("WE DID IT!!!!!!!!!!!");


            }else{
                scanString.append("  WE DID NOT DO IT!!!!!!!!!!!  ");
            }

            */
        }

        // Making if statements to test for advertising data

        /*





        if (majorMinor) {
            scanString.append(" Maj. Mnr.: ");
            if (beacon.getId2() != null) {
                scanString.append(beacon.getId2());
            }
            scanString.append("-");
            if (beacon.getId3() != null) {
                scanString.append(beacon.getId3());
            }
        }

        if (rssi) {
            scanString.append(" RSSI: ").append(beacon.getRssi());
        }

        if (proximity) {
            scanString.append(" Proximity: ").append(BeaconHelper.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()));
        }

        if (power) {
            scanString.append(" Power: ").append(beacon.getTxPower());
        }

        if (timestamp) {
            scanString.append(" Timestamp: ").append(BeaconHelper.getCurrentTimeStamp());
        }  */
    }

    private void logEddystoneTelemetry(StringBuilder scanString, Beacon beacon) {
        // Do we have telemetry data?
        if (beacon.getExtraDataFields().size() > 0) {
            long telemetryVersion = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(0);
            long batteryMilliVolts = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(1);
            long pduCount = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(3);
            long uptime = beacon.getExtraDataFields().get(4);

            scanString.append(" Telemetry version : " + telemetryVersion);
            scanString.append(" Uptime (sec) : " + uptime);
            scanString.append(" Battery level (mv) " + batteryMilliVolts);
            scanString.append(" Tx count: " + pduCount);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param line
     */
    private void logToDisplay(final String line) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                editText.append(line + "\n");

                // Temp code - don't really want to do this for every line logged, will look for a
                // workaround.
                Linkify.addLinks(editText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

                scroller.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

            }
        });
    }

    private void verifyBluetooth() {

        try {
            if (!BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).checkAvailability()) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Bluetooth not enabled");          
                builder.setMessage("Please enable bluetooth in settings and restart this application.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);                 
                    }                   
                });
                builder.show();
            }           
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Bluetooth LE not available");         
            builder.setMessage("Sorry, this device does not support Bluetooth LE.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);                 
                }

            });
            builder.show();

        }

    }

    /* Location services code follows */

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnect the client.
        locationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Uncomment the following line to display the connection status.
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

         /* Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Location services not available, cannot track device location.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;
        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }
        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }
        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
     * by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
             switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                 /*
                  * TODO - Try the request again
                  */
                  break;
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to cast to string first    .toString

if (uuid) {
            scanString.append(" UUID: ").append(beacon.getId1());

```
        // Making if statements to look for all f's in advertising data

        if (beacon.getId1().toString().equals(Str1)){
            scanString.append("\nAlarm ACTIVATED\n");
        }else{
            scanString.append("\n Alarm NOT active\n");
        }
    }
```